# Does google refresh token expire? What are the way so that google refresh token will not expire

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-people-api

```py
import requests
from datetime import datetime

refresh_token = "1//0gGNYTet38TyKCgYIARAAGBASNwF-L9Ir8JMGjR82iiCdPY0bTfdu2gutU50qPGFcASU4EmDWSouvnhvbuGtrEAiijoElpRoUKqg"
client_id = (
    "760863696391-ub3lqtqj4ou3qf4l35vjd3sa5bft14u1.apps.googleusercontent.com"
)
client_secret = "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"

token_endpoint = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"

payload = {
    "refresh_token": refresh_token,
    "client_id": client_id,
    "client_secret": client_secret,
    "grant_type": "refresh_token",
}
# Make the POST request to obtain new access tokens
response = requests.post(token_endpoint, data=payload)
token_data = response.json()
print(response.json())

access_token = token_data.get("access_token")
print(access_token)
refresh_token = token_data.get("refresh_token")
expires_in = token_data.get("expires_in")

print(access_token, "|", refresh_token, "||", expires_in)
```

in above code while getting access token from refresh token it work for sometime but after certain time while trying to get access_token from refresh token it throws

```
{
  'error': 'invalid_grant',
  'error_description': 'reauth related error (invalid_rapt)',
  'error_uri': 'https://support.google.com/a/answer/9368756',
  'error_subtype': 'invalid_rapt'
}
```

I read the docs. I am expecting that once the user gets refresh token it should not expire so that the user should not have to re-login.`

Comment: Refresh tokens can be invalidated at any time for many reasons. You must design for that situation and support reauthentication. Typically they will work for one to two weeks. There are policies that can make reauthorization a requirement in an hour.

Comment: If those are valid secrets delete the client now in the Google Coud console GUI. Editing your question will not help as we can see each edit revision.

Comment: Google has a partial list of reasons [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2?hl=en#expiration).

Answer (score 0):

Per the google docs, the time you can set on the refresh token for authtication is 24 hours.

> > The minimum frequency allowed is 1 hour, and the maximum is 24 hours. The frequency doesn't include how long a user has been inactive
> > in the session. It is the fixed time that elapses before the user
> > needs to sign in again.
>
> You can also check the Exempt trusted apps box to exempt trusted apps
> from reauthentication. (Trusted apps are marked as Trusted on the App
> access control page.

[Google Docs](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9368756)

Comment: This is a good partial answer but only applies to Organizations. My other comment has more to consider.

Comment: To add to my previous comment. Since a Google Workspace principal (email) can be used in multiple projects, your answer can apply to Google Cloud Projects and services that are not part of an organization. However, Workspace is required to create the principals that are managed.